# The pair of backward slash gets replaced by a single slash

Tags: java, regex, string, groovy, replace

A file is being created as a result of an use case and I am mailing the path of the file to the required recipient:

For Ex:

```
Path of the file is 
\\10.123.44.67\D\DestinationFolder
```

and since this path is being picked up by a different function and is obtained as a string obviously all the slashes would be escaped in the string so it would be somewhat like this

```
\\\\10.123.44.67\\D\\\DestinationFolder
```

If I print the String I would get the exact path(i.e only two double slashes at start) but when I am mailing this text I think its getting converted to the HTML text and taking as it is and therefore the mail being received contains four slashes in the start but I want the mail to contain the **exact path** i.e. **(\10.123.44.67\D\DestinationFolder)**

I tried using replace method of groovy like this

```
destinationPath = "\\\\10.123.44.67\\D\\DestinationFolder";
String replacedDestination = destinationPath.replace("\\\\","\\");
```

trying to replace pair of slashes with one above.

But still the output obtained after the changes is:
`\\10.123.44.67\D\` when string is printed in the logs.

while in the email

```
\\10.123.44.67\\D\\DestinationFolder
```

is being received after replace method.

Could please anyone suggest ... how to obtain

`\\10.123.44.67\D\DestinationFolder` in the email itself.

There are multiple things already for replacing double slashes with one slash but none of them were helpful in my case. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try [`String replacedDestination = destinationPath.replaceAll(/(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)/, "\\\\");`](https://ideone.com/ZYWpyI)

Comment: not clear why do you need to escape back-slashes... maybe you need to fix formatting/building email.... html itself does not require to escape back-slashes.

Comment: You realize that `destinationPath = "\\\\10.123.44.67\\D\\DestinationFolder";` will result in the string being `\\10.123.44.67\D\DestinationFolder`? And calling `replace("\\\\", "\\")` on that should result in  `\10.123.44.67\D\DestinationFolder`. If you get some other output I'd suggest checking what you are logging/writing and when. Ideally step through your code with a debugger and check the relevant steps.

Comment: In addition to my comment above: it's hard to tell what's going wrong with as little code as you posted. We neither know how you log the strings nor how you put them into your email - and we also don't know how you receive them (so what format they can be expected to be in).